# UTF-16 to UTF-8 in C

Tags: c, csv, utf-8, utf-16

In C I need to write a program that parses a CSV file encoded in UTF-16 take that information process it, and use that processed information to generate a new UTF-16 csv file.

As of right now all my program does is loads the contents of the CSV file (UTF-16) into a chunk of memory, I now need to somehow work with this UTF-16 chunk of memory and I'm not exactly sure how I'm going to go about doing that without converting it since I can't even use `strlen` or similar on it because of all the `NULL`s it has.

How can I convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 and then back to UTF-16 ? I assume I'm going to need to get the total file size of the original CSV (UTF-16) file by using fseek and what not. But even after that how do I do the conversion?

The reason I'm doing this by the way is because I'm currently working with some "dump" files from WonderWare that are CSV formatted (UTF-16).

Comment: Why use C for what seems like a textbook scripting problem?

Comment: Because C is the only language I know, I learned it from a book that my neighbor threw out. And have been dabbling with the language for a couple years now but have just recently started picking it up. In short I want to use C because I am most familiar with it and like the feel of it. It's just a preference.

Comment: It might actually save you time to learn to use, e.g., Python (which is fairly C-like), or Perl or Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on a *nix system you can use [iconv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv)

Example: `iconv -f UTF16 -t UTF8 file.csv`

Comment: Unfortunately I am on windows.

Comment: You can switch text encoding there.  You might be able to in the editor you use though.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any help!